# Wordpress: Floating sidebar to right not working correctly

Tags: html, css, wordpress, sidebar

http://www.guytgunterappliances.com/product-category/shop/

My #container is currently at width:980px and my side has positioned itself to the bottom of the container div. Im trying to float it to the right of my container div. I have reduced the width of the container to 710px to fit the 270px sidebar then i float the sidebar. As you can see in the image, it stretches the sidebar.It runs over the container div as well.  [image]

## SIDEBAR

```
*************************************************************************/

#sidebar{

position:relative;

z-index:10;

width:270px;
 display:;

}

#sidebar,

#sidebar a,

#sidebar li,

#sidebar ul,

#sidebar ol{

    color:#787878;

    font-size:12px;
 display:;

}

#sidebar a:hover{

}

#sidebar ul{

    list-style:none;

    padding:0;

    margin:0;

}

    #sidebar ul li.widget{

        margin:0 0 0px 0;

        border:1px solid #fff;

        background: #e6e6e6;

    }

    #sidebar ul li.widget h2{

        font-size:18px;

        padding:13px 18px;

        color:#45494e;

        font-style:normal;

        border:1px solid #cecece;

        border-bottom:1px solid #fff;

    }

        #sidebar ul li ul{

            border:1px solid #cecece;

            border-bottom:none;

        }

            #sidebar ul li ul li{

                border-bottom:1px solid #cecece;

                padding: 10px 18px;

            }

            #sidebar ul li ul li:hover{

                border-bottom:1px solid #cecece;

                padding: 10px 18px;

                background:#eee;

            }

                #sidebar ul li ul li ul{

                    padding:0 0 0 15px;

                    border:none;

                }

                    #sidebar ul li ul li ul li{

                        border-bottom:none;

                        }

            /* TEXT WIDGET */

            #sidebar ul li div.textwidget{

                padding: 10px 18px;

                line-height:1.4em;

                border:1px solid #cecece;

            }

            /* TAG CLOUD */

            #sidebar ul li.widget_tag_cloud div{

                padding: 10px 18px;

                border:1px solid #cecece;

            }

                #sidebar ul li.widget_tag_cloud div a{

                    margin:0 10px 0 0;

                }

            /* CALENDAR */

            #sidebar ul li.widget_calendar{

                border:1px solid #fff;

            }

                #sidebar ul li.widget_calendar #calendar_wrap table#wp-calendar{

                    padding: 10px 18px;

                    width:100%;

                    border:1px solid #cecece;

                    border-top:none;

                }

                    #sidebar ul li.widget_calendar #calendar_wrap table#wp-calendar a{

                        text-decoration: underline;

                    }

                    #sidebar ul li.widget_calendar #calendar_wrap table#wp-calendar caption{

                        padding: 5px 18px 0 18px;

                        border:1px solid #cecece;

                        border-bottom:none;

                    }

                    #sidebar ul li.widget_calendar #calendar_wrap table#wp-calendar tr td#next{

                    text-align:right;

                    }

/************************************************************************

#  SIDEBAR END
```

Comment: you have two `div`s with id `container` on main page, one of which is containing both the second one and the sidebar. fix that first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few steps required to fix that issue:

1. you have two `div`s with id `container` on main page, the inner one and the outer one. Change id of one of those.
2. for the inner `#container`, add:

   ```
   width: 710px;
   float: left;
   ```
3. reduce width of `#content` and `iframe` to 710px or less.
4. finally, style `#sidebar` as @KaronatoR suggests:

   ```
   width:270px;
   display: block;
   float: left;
   ```

Comment: doing this floats the entire content of my site to the left so that there is no centered container.

Comment: the float in the "container" div does it

Comment: it floats the entire content of your site to the left because of the outer `#container` div, which contains the whole site.

Comment: what would you recommend to fix the outer container?

Answer (score 0):

Try so:

```
#sidebar {
  width:270px;
  display: block;
  dloat: left;
}
```

Comment: this just made it float left to the footer